# $h = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (ae^{j\omega})^n$ , how is the approximation of this equal to $\frac {1}{1-h}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, time-series, z-transform

the question in the title. im working on a z- transform problem. 
to find the Z - transform of $x(n) = a^ncos(\omega n)u(n)$, u(n) being the step unit function

essentially i come down to the answer being

$$X(z) = (1/2) [\sum_{n=0}^\infty (ae^{j\omega}z^{-1})^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty (ae^{-j\omega}z^{-1})^n]$$

however in the solution they were able to simply this answer and thus removing the summation.

solution is

$$(\frac12) [\frac{1}{1-ae^{j\omega}z^{-1}} + \frac{1}{1-ae^{-jw}z^{-1}}]$$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  Please take a moment to visit [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to read an introduction on how to type mathematics on the site to make your posts more readable.

Comment: sweet. thanks was wondering how i can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a standard result for the sum of a geometric series (where $x$ may be real or as we need here, complex):
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n x^{k}= \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}
$$
which you can see by multiplying out $(1-x)\sum_{0}^nx^k$ which gives a telescoping sum equal to $1-x^{n+1}$.

Now if $|x|<1$ the sum converges as $n\to \infty$ and the result is:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{k}= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}=\frac{1}{1-x}
$$

Other ways to see this is to consider the binomial series , or the Maclaurin series for: $(1-x)^{-1}$

Comment: thanks!!! its the principle of mathematical induction right

Comment: The finite sum could be proven by induction but that is not how it has been demonstrated here.